# Premiere Pro CS6: how to change color of a clip as time progresses?

Tags: premiere, effects, color, cs6

I am trying out a few things for PPro, since I'm new to it (coming from Camtasia Studio 8) and I'm wondering, since a lot can be done, is it possible to not have the clip with a black and white effect, but have it 'walk along' the whole color spectrum?

In Windows Movie Maker for XP there used to be an effect like that, so you can see what I mean here:

As you can see, the color of the clip is never the same.

Can this be done somehow? A ton of Google and Youtube searches have not provided me an answer to this question; most hits are about Color Correction and I couldnt really see anything that came close to this.

Thanks in advance!

- DiaborMagics

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. The basic idea is always the same: You overlay a color and then animate it's hue. To get rid of all other color, you can either convert the footage to black-and-white (which can again be achieved using different techniques) or put the color on an adjustment layer with the blending mode set to color. This is the preferred way to do it, since this way, you can apply the effect to your entire scene at once. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this effect using the Lumetri Color workspace (which is not available on CS6 and earlier versions).

1. Create a new adjustment layer (*File* → *New* → *Adjustment Layer*) and put it over your video clips in the timeline of your sequence.
2. Select the adjustment layer in the sequence and change to the *Color* workspace (*Window* → *Workspaces* → *Color*). The *Lumetri Color* panel should now be on the right side of the program window.
3. In the *Lumetri Color* panel, under *Basic Correction*, reduce the *Saturation* to 0. Your video should now be black-and-white.
4. Under *Creative*, set a color for the *Shadow Tint* and move the *Tint Balance* slider all the way to the right (100). Your video should now be monochrome.
5. Open the *Effect Settings* panel (make sure the adjustment layer is still selected) and find the *Shadow Tint* setting under the *Lumetri Color* effect (this one is automatically applied once you change a setting in the Lumetri Color panel). Hit the stopwatch icon to activate the animation for that effect property and set the first keyframe (make sure the playhead is positioned at the first frame of the adjustment layer first). Now it's time to get creative, set keyframes at appropriate intervals and change the *Shadow Tint* to different settings every time. Premiere Pro will interpolate between the values, giving you the color transition effect you wanted.
6. **Optional:** Under *Opacity*, set the blending mode of the adjustment layer to *Color*. This way, the original luminosity values are preserved, making the effect more subtle. You can also try *Hue* for an even more subtle effect or change the opacity of the adjustment layer. This will reduce the color overlay effect, allowing some of the original clip colors to come through.

---

#### Workaround for CS6

Since the Lumetri Color panel doesn't exist in CS6, you will need to use another color correction effect instead. The basic idea will stay the same though. You can for example use the *Tint* effect in the same way as described above (you will have to set keyframes for both *Map Black To* and *Map White To*, since there is no balance slider in this effect). With the introduction of the Lumetri Color panel, a lot of the old CS6 color correction effects got deprecated in the new CC version. If you are still on CS6, you could for example also use the *Three-Way-* or *Fast Color Corrector* to get similar results.

---

Or just do it in After Effects using Layer Styles → Color overlay, set the Blend Mode of the effect to Color and animate the Color.

Comment: oh thank you very, very much for this thorough explanation! I'm going to try that out as soon as I can!

Comment: @DiaborMagics If this works for you, feel free to mark my answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: I'm sure your answer is correct, I'm just a noob. I indeed use CS6 and I can add the adjustment layer and Tint effect, but man.... blending colors the right way and animating that is difficult, especially if I want to cross the entire color spectrum. All my attempts so far..... are just plain terrible :S
Probably also has to do with my lack of understanding when it comes to colors and computers, color correction and proper blending with the million settings per slider, now for 2 sliders, across an animation :P Are you sure theres no drag-n-drop effect for this? XD

Comment: @DiaborMagics Sure? No ... there's always a hidden submenu somewhere in Premiere that will do exactly the thing you want it to do, the only problem is to find it ^^' But as far as I'm aware there's no Layer Styles in Premiere Pro, so no color overlay ... I also haven't found a way to cycle through the color of e.g. a solid color layer ... do you have After Effects? Since it's really easy with AE, see the sidenote in my answer.

Comment: Like I explained in my own answer above I have found a way to cycle through the color spectrum and its really easy. The only downside is that its doesnt change every detail to the respective colors, but is indeed more like a color filter; the more intense you set the color, the more of that color you see and the more footage turns into that color, but that also sacrifices a lot of detail. Like a strong filter... if you get what im saying :P

Comment: @DiaborMagics Your solution is the same as mine ^^ Notice in the paragraph about CS6 workarounds I recommended the Fast Color Corrector as an alternative to the Lumetri Color Panel. If you don't want any of the original color to come through, set the saturation to zero in a seperate adjustment layer or effect (below the color one). If you feel the Fast Color Corrector doesn't give you enough options, try a more elaborate effect such as the Three-Way Color Corrector, they will give you more control over the color adjustment

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since I think I just found a good solution for noobs like myself, I will add this as a separate answer and indeed one to my own question.

In CS6 PPro, I found the 'Fast Color Corrector' effect. This one is very powerful and a lot faster indeed. I accomplished a much better result than before in mere minutes.

1. Create an adjustment layer and put it over the clip/sequence/entire film, whatever you want, like in the previous answer
2. Go to the Effects tab and search 'fast'. Then find the Fast Color Corrector and put it on the Adjustment Layer on the timeline
3. Make sure your playhead is at the start of the Adjustment layer (for me that was 00:00 so that was easy)
4. Set Balance Angle to 140, so that you get too much green
5. Adjust Balance Magnitude until you're satisfied with how much green you see
6. Check your color range by scratching Balance Angle from 0 - 360
7. Set the Balance Angle to your starting point, which may be 0, or whatever else you want
8. Click the Balance Angle stopwatch to set a keyframe
9. Drag the playhead to the end of the Adjustment Layer; if you're at the end and want to refine where the playhead is, you can use the left and right arrow keys
10. Add 360 to your initial starting point to move across the spectrum
11. If you wish to move across the spectrum twice, or more, just add more Adjustment Layers next to each other to mark the beginning and end of each cycle and repeat the steps to animate the effect
12. EDIT (this item wasnt on the list before) Its a good idea to select the effect when done, or select all applied effects and right-click -> add preset, so that you can apply is more easily next time

11B - Something I just noticed is that you can move across the spectrum twice or more, simply by adding more cycles to Balanc Angle. So if you start at 0 and wish to move across once, stop at 360. Otherwise, simply use 720 or more, to move across twice or more.